# Is the sum of positive definite matrices still positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, positive-definite

I have two symmetric positive definite (SPD) matrices. I would like to prove that the sum of these two matrices is still SPD. Symmetry is obvious, but what about PD-ness? Any clues, please?

Comment: Guys, his question has nothing to do with matrix products...

Comment: Do you agree with my edits?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

A real matrix $M$ is positive-definite if and only if it is symmetric and $u^TMu > 0$ for all nonzero vectors $u$.

Now if $A$ and $B$ are positive-definite, $u^T(A+B)u = \ldots?$

Comment: Why is symmetric condition necessary, for a real matrix, to be Pos. def. ? 
How about $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\-1&1\end{pmatrix}$, which is non-symmetric but still Pos. definite?

Comment: @kaka The *definition* of a positive-definite matrix includes that it is symmetric (or Hermitian, if complex). You can talk about matrices which satisfy some positive-definite-like properties, such as $u^TMu > 0$ for nonzero $u$, without being symmetric, but this is not a standard definition.

Comment: The reason behind that definition is that it comes from *quadratic forms* $x^T A x$. That is positive definite if it is positive for all $x \not = 0$.  You can check that for such quadtatic forms, we only need to consider symmetric matrices. That is, if $A$ is not symmetric, you can replace it with $\frac{A+A^T}{2}$ without changing the form.

Comment: Geometrically, it means that $Mu\in H_u$, where $H_u = \{v: u \cdot v > 0 \}$ is the positive half-space defined by $u$. Then $Au + Bu \in H_u$ since $H_u + H_u = H_u$. Similarly for semi-definite matrices.

Comment: Does it also hold the opposite? $(A+B)$ nonnegative definite $\implies$ A and B nonnegative definite?

Comment: @MrFrog No. For an easy counterexample consider $A = 2I$ and $B = -I$.

Answer (score 26):

This is an more detailed  answer.

Now let $ A $ and $B$ be positive definite matrices, that is  for all $ h \; \in \mathbb{R} ^{n}$ we must have $ h^{T}Ah > 0 $ and  $ h^{T}Bh > 0 $.

From properties of real numbers

$0 < h^{T}Bh + h^{T}Ah $

Now from the distributive laws of matrix multiplication we must have

$0< h^{T}Bh + h^{T}Ah =h^{T} (B  + A)h  $

This implies that  $0<h^{T} (B  + A)h  $  meaning  $ B+A \succ 0$.

That is $ B+A $ is positive definite.

Answer (score -4):

A+B, or B+A, is positive definite if both A and B are positive definite. Suppose A is a m1*n1 matrix and B is a m2*n2 matrix. Because you can sum them up, m1=m2, n1=n2. Since then, as you add up these two matrices, the properties of leading principal minors will not change from the old. Since then, A+B is positive definite. Good luck!