# Proving positive (semi-)definiteness of a matrix equation for Cholseky decomposition.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, matrix-decomposition, positive-semidefinite

I'm trying to prove, or disprove, that the following matrix is positive (semi-)definite and symmetric (so a covariance matrix);
$$
M = C_M^{-1} + G^T C_D^{-1} G.
$$
Here, $C_M$ is a covariance matrix (which is positive semi-definite and symmetric, sometimes positive definite)  of dimensions $n \times n$, which is not necessarily diagonal. The matrix $C_D$, of dimensions $m \times m$, is also a covariance matrix which in my application is always diagonal, but could be extended to any arbitrary covariance matrix (so always positive semi-definite, symmetric).

G is an arbitrary matrix of dimensions $m \times n$. It does not necessarily have full rank. I think this already excludes positive definiteness of the second term, since $x^T G^T G x = (G x)^T(G x) > 0$ only if G is full rank.

Can we extend this to $G^T C_D^{-1} G$ to prove that M is positive semi-definite symmetric? I'd suggest to use the property $x^T A x \geq 0$;

$$
\begin{eqnarray} 
x^T G^T C_D^{-1} G x &=& (G x)^T C_D^{-1} (G x)     \nonumber \\
& \overset{?}{\geq} & 0
\end{eqnarray} 
$$

I guess this boils down to proving that the inverse of $C_D$ (and $C_M$) is positive semi-definite, because afterwards we can again use the same definition on $(G x)^T C_D^{-1} (G x) $. And the sum of PSD matrices is also PSD (that proof is rather easy, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544139/sum-of-positive-definite-matrices-still-positive-definite)).

And then a small follow up; if the second term is PSD, but the first term is PD, the resulting matrix M is also PD right?

For a little context, from the first equation matrix $M$ is used as the mass matrix in a Hamiltonian Monte Carlo sampler, and I need to Cholesky decompose it to propose momentum samples. Cholesky decomposition can (I think) only be done on a positive definite matrix. If a matrix is positive semi-definite, it is still possible to Cholesky decompose it if the diagonal entries of $L$ are allowed to be zero, but I don't know if my algorithm breaks down in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a matrix $A$ is symmetric positive definite, then $A^{-1}$ is symmetric positive definite.

Proof:  Let the SVD of $A=UDU^T$, then $A^{-1}=UD^{-1}U^T$, we can see from the eigenvalues that $A^{-1}$ is positive definite.

If a matrix $A$ is positive definite and matrix $B$ is symmetric positive semidefinite, then $A+B$ is positive definite.

Proof:

$$x^T(A+B)x=x^TAx+x^TBx > 0$$

Comment: Thanks, easy as 1, 2, 3, both proofs! The term $ (G x)^T C_D^{-1} (G x) $ then also proves PD/PSD right?

Comment: If $C_D$ is positive definite then $(Gx)^TC_D^{-1}(Gx) \geq 0$, hence it is PSD. I don't think it is PD as $Gx$ can be zero even though $x$ is non-zero.

Comment: So the requirement for $M$ to be PD if $C_M$ is PSD is that $G$ has full rank, and $C_D$ is PD.